# Parse relative data using h2 in jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I am trying to get some data from a website using Jsoup in java but am having some difficulties figuring out how exactly to get it. I have an array of item names and only want to get the items from the website with similar names. The names are stored in an h2 as you see in the html code provided below, I am trying to get the relative src using the data in the h2 to locate it.

An Example snippet of the html I am working with:
(there are multiples of these divs)

```
<div class="item-class" data-name="nameOfItem">
    <div id="item-3000" class="second-item-class">
        <img src="/content/items/getthis.png">
        <h2>I have these item names</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only got as far as thinking of how to locate the h2's, but couldn't even manage to get that to work, so I figured someone might know how to locate the data using the h2 data I have, matching the two up, and the somehow retrieving the src data. The following is what I tried so far to find the h2 data:
(just for clarification the names of variables is to get the point across, they aren't actually named this in my code)

```
for(int i = 0; i < h2ItemNames.size(); i++){
    Elements srcData = doc.select(h2ItemNames.get(i));
    System.out.println("srcData: " + srcData.toString());
}
```

Wondering if this is even possible or if I should be taking a different route, in my mind its completely feasible, I just haven't worked with jsoup enough to work this out more than I already have. Hoping someone knows how to get to the src data after locating the h2 through the data held within rather than searching for the tag itself (that i know how to do) since there are many of them throughout the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `h2` already selected you can reach `img` by getting previousElementSibling:

```
for(int i = 0; i < h2ItemNames.size(); i++){
    Element h2 = doc.select(h2ItemNames.get(i)).first();
    Element img = h2.previousElementSibling();
    String src = img.attr("src");
    System.out.println("src: " + src);
}
```

but if `img` is not always previous element you can try moving one level up and selecting first `img`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < h2ItemNames.size(); i++){
    Element h2 = doc.select(h2ItemNames.get(i)).first();
    Element parent = h2.parent();
    Element img = parent.select("img").first();
    String src = img.attr("src");
    System.out.println("src: " + src);
}
```

Comment: If the full src path is needed one can use `.attr("abs:src")` instead of reconstructing the full path from src and host yourselft.

Comment: After a lot of fiddling around, Thank you for the code above, it did help a lot. I had to make one change though.
Element h2 = doc.select("h2:contains(" + h2ItemNames.get(i) + ")").first(); 
This allows the array to be used as a string variable, if i was just searching with the variable like in the code you provided it would return a null object